# Best approach to index a PostgreSQL database with plain html content?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, full-text-search

I have a database with a few million posts, each with a column "content" that contains the post content in plain HTML.

```html
<div class="quoteheader"><a href="http://website.com/message?id=52501">
Quote from: X on October 22, 2013, 02:07:08 PM</a>
</div>
<div class="quote">
Hi, how are you all?
<br></div>
<br>I'm good, how about you?
```

I want to make a full search tool that allows people to search for a post. In this case, someone could search "how are you" and it would result in this post.

I thought about creating a ts_vector index using gin:

`CREATE INDEX posts_content_search ON posts using gin(to_tsvector('simple', content));`

To allow those kind of searches.

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE to_tsvector('simple', content) @@ phraseto_tsquery('simple', 'how are you');`

However, while creating it, not only it keeps showing a lot of those messages:

```
DETAIL:  Words longer than 2047 characters are ignored.
NOTICE:  word is too long to be indexed
```

but it also saves the html tags in the index (e.g: div, b, a, br...), while the best would be to remove the tags and index only the post real content ("hi, how are you all" and "i'm good, how about you")

What would be the best approach to creating an index to allow such kind of search?

Comment: Don't index the whole column `content` but the only the messages inside it (such as `Hi, how are you all?` and `I'm good, how about you?`). You'll need to preprocess the data, maybe by simply removing all tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'simple' already excludes the contents of html tags, as can be seen from the output of `strip(to_tsvector('simple',content))`:

```
                                                         strip                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 '02' '07' '08' '2013' '22' 'about' 'all' 'are' 'from' 'good' 'hi' 'how' 'i' 'm' 'october' 'on' 'pm' 'quote' 'x' 'you'
```

Note the absence of 'br', 'div', etc.

The "Quote from: X" part is included because that was not in a tag.  If you want to exclude that, what logic would you want to use to do so?

The warnings about long words can just be ignored.  If you want advice on fixing them, you should show us an example which produces them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought I had seen some tags after using to_tsvector with the 'simple' dictionary (like 'div'). Maybe I was wrong? That's what I used a bit later after posting the question: `CREATE INDEX posts_content_search ON posts using gin(to_tsvector('simple', regexp_replace(regexp_replace(content, E'<br>', ' ', 'gi'), E'Quote from:.*<\\/div>|<[^>]*>|(_|-){3,}', '', 'gi')));`. But now, that doesn't seem to be the best idea... I managed to see what the longer words looked like. Some are really big links, like a google search link with ruberish. I will just ignore them.